# Using Hibernate OGM, why does String sequence generator create 2 element for each insertion?

Tags: jpa, hibernate-ogm

I m using this gegnerator

```
public class StringIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {
    final public static String NAME=StringIdGenerator.class.getSimpleName();
    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object) throws HibernateException {


        return  UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-","");
    }
}



@Entity
@GenericGenerator(name = "pt_sequence", strategy = "dao.StringIdGenerator")

public class P {
@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY,generator = "pt_sequence")
   String id; 
.......
```

Why after a insertion i see 2 element inserted , not one?

Comment: Hi, we are trying to reproduce the issue, could you add some more information? Which version of Hibernate OGM are you using? Which datastore? At the moment our tests seem to work. Thanks

Comment: We might also need to see how you are inserting the entities

Comment: By the way, is the problem occurring if you don't use the custom generator?

Comment: I removed it and add id manually. In this way it works

Comment: I'm glad that you have found a work-around. If you can still give us some more information or a small testcase to check the problem. We might be able to reproduce it and solve it.

Comment: What are you trying to do should work and you shouldn't have to set the id manually (if you don't want to).